# Compute the negative numbers in an array

Tags: java, negative-number

I was searching for solution to find negative numbers in array and i came up with something like this code from searching.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int arrayNumbers[] = { 3, 4, 7, -3, -2};
    for (int i = 0; i <= arrayNumbers.length; i++){
        int negativeCount = 0;
        if (arrayNumbers[i] >= 0){
                negativeCount++;
    }
    System.out.println(negativeCount);
    }
}
```

I was wondering is there an easier or shorter way to find the negative number in an array vs the code above?

Comment: That's counting the `>= 0`, not the negative numbers.

Comment: That code will generate an out of bounds exception due to the terminating condition in the `for`.

Comment: That code wont compile at all, you cannot access negativeCount outside of the for loop.

Comment: @hmjd So there is a shorter way.  ;)

Comment: You have to put `int negativeCount = 0;` before the loop. Otherwise the counter will be initialized to `0` with each iteration

Comment: A possibly more efficient way is to check the value whenever you add/set an array element, and maintain the resulting count during the array´s lifetime. That way, you never would have to look at the array as a whole, counting the negative numbers -- you would always know how many negatives you´ve put in there so far.

Comment: @TheBlastOne There is no way in java to do this.

Comment: @Boh agree, provided the array is initialized as shown. If it is filled "by code", you indeed can increment the "negative" count when adding and decrement when removing a negative int to/from the array. (I assume OP uses the initialized array to keep the question simple, but in reality uses some algorithm to build the contents as a non-constant, i.e. with code.)

Comment: @TheBlastOne What are you talking about? Precisely how can you "increment the negative count" when adding/removing elements from an array?

Comment: Like so: If you have a method that sets an elem´s value in the array, then in this method, you could inspect the value, and increment a global int variable (or field) negativeCount by one if the value is negative. Then you would not have to recalculate the number of negatives lateron. (int negativeCount would need to be initialized to zero and propertly maintained, of course.). I just don't believe the values in the array come from the array initializer in the array´s declaration in OP´s real code.

Answer (score 8):

A java 7 string-based one-liner that counts the minus signs:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll("[^-]+", "").length());
```

---

A Java 8 stream-based way:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(array).filter(i -> i < 0).count());
```

---

Regarding your code, there are a few things wrong with it:

- Since you don't care about the index of an element, use the [foreach syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) instead
- Declare the scope of your count variable *outside* the loop, otherwise

  - it keeps getting set to zero every iteration, and
  - you couldn't use it even if it did contain the correct count because it would be out of scope (which would be only inside the loop) where you need to return it (after the loop)
- Use the correct test `number < 0` (your code `>= 0` counts *non* negative numbers)

Try this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] array = { 3, 4, 7, -3, -2};
    int negativeCount = 0;
    for (int number : array) {
        if (number < 0) {
            negativeCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(negativeCount);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A few issues with the code:

- the terminating condition in the `for` will produce an out of bounds exception (arrays use zero-based index)
- the scope of `negativeCount` is within the `for` only
- the negative check is incorrect

A slightly shorter version would use the extended `for`:

```
int negativeCount = 0;
for (int i: arrayNumbers)
{
    if (i < 0) negativeCount++;
}
```

For a shorter version (but arguably less readable) eliminate the `for`'s `{}`:

```
int negativeCount = 0;
for (int i: arrayNumbers) if (i < 0) negativeCount++;
```

Comment: Does this code still work without adding -- > this line of code -->int[] array = { 3, 4, 7, -3, -2}; not understanding how its initializing the array elements

Comment: @PHZEOXIDE, I just did not add that to the snippets, it is required.

Answer (score 0):

Your negativeCount should be declared outside your loop.. Also, you can move your `System.out.println(negativeCount)` outside your loop, as it will print for every iteration..

And you can use **enhanced-for** loop

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int arrayNumbers[] = { 3, 4, 7, -3, -2};

    int negativeCount = 0;
    for (int num: arrayNumbers) {
        if (num < 0){
                negativeCount++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(negativeCount);
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `Integer` here, `int` works with arrays

Comment: That makes more sense can you explain how the for each loop is different from the regular for loop in java?  thanks

Comment: @PHZEOXIDE.. You can go through [JLS - enhanced for-loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter with the foreach syntax:

```
 int negativeCount = 0;
 for(int i : arrayNumbers)
 {
      if(i < 0)negativeCount++;
 }
```

Comment: Does this code still work without adding 
 -- > this line of code  -->int[] array = { 3, 4, 7, -3, -2};
not understanding how its initializing the array elements.

Comment: @PHZEOXIDE you have to add the line to initialize the array and the line to print negativeCount, my code only does the counting.